# MultiSelect passing value to another iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am trying to separate multiselect with two side in different html.
In **Main.html** put select name **from[]**.
Another **sub.html** put select name **to[]**.
Then, my main.html using iframe to display sub.html.
My quection is, how can I passing selected value in Main Frame Value to iframe

Here is my Main.html code (from[]) https://jsfiddle.net/mouseshop318/yv7fdpj7/21/

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
  <select name="from[]" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="1">Item 1</option>
     <option value="2">Item 5</option>
     <option value="2">Item 2</option>
     <option value="2">Item 4</option>
     <option value="3">Item 3</option>
 </select>
</div>
<iframe src ="sub.html"></iframe>
```

sub.html code (to[])
https://jsfiddle.net/mouseshop318/khqkv628/6/

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
    <select name="to[]" id="search_to" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple"></select>
</div>
```

js

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.multiselect').multiselect();
 });
```

ref:http://crlcu.github.io/multiselect/examples/data-options.html

Comment: Could use postMessage(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage or just call window.parent.anyfunction(values)

Comment: Can you please provide fiddle?